# Julia: converting column type from Integer to Float64 in a DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, julia

I am trying to change type of numbers in a column of a DataFrame from integer to floating point. It should be straightforward to do this, but it's not working. The data type remains to be integer. What am I missing?

```
In  [2]: using DataFrames
df = DataFrame(A = 1:4, B = ["M", "F", "F", "M"])

Out [2]: 4x2 DataFrame
| Row | A | B   |
|-----|---|-----|
| 1   | 1 | "M" |
| 2   | 2 | "F" |
| 3   | 3 | "F" |
| 4   | 4 | "M" |

In  [3]: df[:,:A] = float64(df[:,:A])

Out [3]: 4-element DataArray{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 2.0
 3.0
 4.0

In  [4]: df

Out [4]: 4x2 DataFrame
| Row | A | B   |
|-----|---|-----|
| 1   | 1 | "M" |
| 2   | 2 | "F" |
| 3   | 3 | "F" |
| 4   | 4 | "M" |

In  [5]: typeof(df[:,:A])

Out [5]: DataArray{Int64,1} (constructor with 1 method)
```

Comment: Please [format your code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: @DanielSchroeder Done! Sorry about that.

Comment: I've updated my answer and suggested in it that you might want to consider filing an issue. The behaviour you point out is (to me) very unintuitive (although there may be a good reason for it).

Comment: Just filed an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason this happens is mutation and conversion. 
If you have two vectors

```
a = [1:3]
b = [4:6]
```

you can make `x` refer to one of them with assignment.

```
x = a
```

Now `x` and `a` refer to the same vector `[1, 2, 3]`. If you then assign `b` to `x`

```
x = b
```

you have now changed `x` to refer to the same vector as `b` refers to.

You can also mutate vectors by copying over the values in one vector to the other. If you do

```
x[:] = a
```

you copy over the values in vector `a` to the vector `b`, so now you have two vectors with `[1, 2, 3]`.

Then there is also conversion. If you copy a value of one type into a vector of another value Julia will attempt to convert the value to that of the elements vector.

```
x[1] = 5.0
```

This gives you a the vector `[5, 2, 3]` because Julia converted the `Float64` value `5.0` to the `Int` value `5`. If you tried

```
x[1] = 5.5
```

Julia will throw a `InexactError()` because `5.5` can't be losslessly converted to an integer.

When it comes to DataFrames things work the same as long as you realize a DataFrame is a collection of named references to vectors. So what you are doing when constructing the DataFrame in this call

```
df = DataFrame(A = 1:4, B = ["M", "F", "F", "M"])
```

is that you create the vector `[1, 2, 3, 4]`, and the vector `["M", "F", "F", "M"]`. You then construct a DataFrame with references to these two new vectors.

Later when you do

```
df[:,:A] = float64(df[:,:A])
```

you first create a new vector by converting the values in the vector `[1, 2, 3, 4]` into `Float64`. You then mutate the vector referred to with `df[:A]` by copying over the values in the `Float64` vector back into the `Int` vector, which causes Julia to convert the values back to `Int`.

What Colin T Bower's answer

```
df[:A] = float64(df[:A])
```

does is that rather than mutating the vector referred to by the DataFrame, he changes the reference to refer to the vector with the `Flaot64` values.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: This no longer works with Julia 0.6 (and possibly before) as constructors no longer convert between types. The only solution I found is using explicitly the `convert` function: `df[:A] = convert(DataArrays.DataArray{Float64,1},df[:A])`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df[:A] = float64(df[:A])
```

This works for me on Julia v0.3.5 with DataFrames v0.6.1.

This is quite interesting though. Notice that:

```
df[:, :A] = [2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

will change the contents of the column to `[2,2,3,4]`, but leaves the type as `Int64`, while

```
df[:A] = [2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
```

will also change the type.

I just had quick look at the manual and couldn't see any reference to this behaviour (admittedly it was a very quick look). But I find this unintuitive enough that perhaps it is worth [filing an issue](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl).

Comment: Great. Works for me too. Strange that the former does not work!